# How to force py2app to run app in 32-bit mode

Tags: python, macos, 32-bit, py2app

I am trying to build an app bundle with py2app on Mac OS X 10.6. The app uses some libraries which are only compiled for 32-bit, so when the app is run there is an ImportError "no appropriate 64-bit architecture". How can I tell py2app to force the app to run in 32-bit mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use a 32-bit-only Python, such as the 32-bit-only versions downloadable from python.org, with py2app.  Another is to set the `LSArchitecturePriority` to `i386` and possibly `ppc` in the generated app bundle's Info.plist.  See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the 32-bit build on python.org.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I had to use [the ditto solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8320517/17498).

Comment: on 1.6.8 once I have made an app for dist, then I have edited info.plist in Property List Editor by adding in the root of the tree a set (offered in popup) which is called "Architecture Priority". I was amazed that default setting immediately offered i386. Saved. After this intervention app started without 32bit error.

Comment: I'll take that back: it _does_ work. My mistake was making the value a string rather than an array of strings.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to run only in 32 bit mode, then you don't need the 64 bit architecture. So you can just strip out all the non-i386 architectures from your resulting application bundle using the `ditto` utility.

Example:

```
ditto --rsrc --arch i386 YourApplication.app YourApplicationStripped.app
```

Your application bundle will be smaller and will run as a 32 bit application for sure, even on 64 bit Intel systems.

Manual: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ditto.1.html

Or just run in a terminal: `man ditto`

Answer (score 4):

After lots of pain and trying to get wx working I managed to get it to work using this method, I have also included the versions I installed 
This was the only one that worked for me, I hope it helps others..

```
py2applet --arch=i386 -i (includes here) --make-setup (pythonfiles, icon)
```

Mine looks a bit like this

```
py2applet --arch=i386 -i wx, platform --make-setup print.py print.icns convert.py
```

I installed python2.7 with
wxPython2.8-osx-unicode-py2.7
setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
and then

```
sudo easy_install-2.7 py2app
```

This installed version 0.6.4 of py2applet

Answer (score 1):

OK, seeing as I work one office over from Vebjorn, possibly this is the best place to post an answer so we will find it again. Given a dictionary of py2app options:

```
options = {}
...
options['plist'] = { "LSArchitecturePriority": [ "i386" ] }
...
setup(options={'py2app':options})
```

This creates an array of one string value for the LSArchitecturePriority key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to force python to run in 32-bit mode.

Comment: Yes. I'm running setup.py with arch -i386, but the built app still tries to run as 64-bit.