# Script to open in 32-bit mode?

Tags: python, py2app

I'm making a mac app with wxpython, and when I bundle it with py2app, I get the "no appropriate 64-bit architecture" message. This can be fixed by checking "open in 32-bit mode" in the Get Info panel, but this isn't very convenient for people using the app. Is there a line I can add to my script to make it run in 32-bit, even though Python's default is 64-bit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472301/how-to-force-py2app-to-run-app-in-32-bit-mode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a 32-bit-only version of the app using `ditto`:

```
ditto --rsrc --arch i386 dist/MyApp.app dist/MyApp-32.app
```

`MyApp-32.app` will be an application bundle that only starts in 32-bit mode. As a nice bonus, `ditto` strips out the 64-bit architecture entirely, leaving you with a smaller application bundle (around half the size in my testing).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes
```

when you install your program. This will start python with 32 bit.

This has to be run inside a bash terminal with optional super user privileges.

### `start_your_program.sh`

```
export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes
./main.py
```